# Can't interact with comments while editing in H&I

Tags: bug, comments, help-improvement

I was editing in the Help and Improvement queue, and I spotted a comment I wanted to up vote. I moved my mouse into the red free-hand circle:

> [image]

The icons come up, but clicking does nothing. I couldn't flag the comment, either (no flag dialog).

(After I saved the edits, I was able to vote/flag comments again.)